# Better Java API for elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am starting out on Elasticsearch. The scalability and performance is awesome, but I'm having trouble with the java API. Given some profile data where the id is a username and the profile contains attributes and scores (eg strength : 30, dexterity : 72, magic : 48) I want to get the top profiles for a particular combination of attributes eg strength + dexterity, or strength + magic etc.

Here is a query that I've used in Sense, which does exactly what I need:

```
GET_search{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "group by profile": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "profileId",
                "order": {
                    "score_return": "desc"
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "score_return": {
                    "sum": {
                        "script": "doc['strength'].value + doc['dexterity'].value"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So now I want to port this query into my Java code. I managed to get it working, but it feels like it's extremely ugly - is there a better way of querying this data, or perhaps some library out there with a nice API, that can bind results to fields with annotations etc? Any suggestions welcome. This is what I have so far (it works, I just don't like the look of the code):

```
private void run() throws UnknownHostException {

    InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(HOST_IP);
    InetSocketTransportAddress transportAddress = new InetSocketTransportAddress(inetAddress, HOST_PORT);

    Client client = TransportClient.builder().build().addTransportAddress(transportAddress);


    String queryString = "{ \"aggs\": {  \"group by profile\": {   \"terms\": {   \"field\": \"profileId\", \"order\": { \"score_return\": \"desc\" } }, \"aggs\": { \"score_return\": { \"sum\": { \"script\": \"doc['dexterity'].value + doc['strength'].value\" } } } } } }";

    //Sample Query - JSONObject
    //We convert the raw query string to JSONObject to avoid query parser error in Elasticsearch
    JSONObject queryStringObject = new JSONObject(queryString);

    //Elasticsearch Response
    SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("profiles").setTypes("profile").setSource(queryStringObject.toString()).execute().actionGet();

    //Elasticsearch Response Hits
    SearchHits hits = response.getHits();
    Aggregations aggregations = response.getAggregations();

    Map<String, Aggregation> aggsMap = aggregations.asMap();
    Aggregation groupBy = aggsMap.get("group by profile");
    System.out.println(groupBy);

    StringTerms st = ((StringTerms)groupBy);
    System.out.println(st);

    List<Bucket> buckets = st.getBuckets();
    for(Bucket bucket : buckets) {
        System.out.println(bucket.getKeyAsString());
        Aggregation score = bucket.getAggregations().get("score_return");
        String value = ((InternalSum)score).getValueAsString();
        System.out.println(value);
    }

    client.close();

}
```

Comment: You should have a look at [Jest](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/)